# Composer connection

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to make laravel project with composer with bellow cmd cod:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel-santcum-api
```

but I get error like this:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  curl error 7 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/laravel/laravel.json: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 p
  ort 1797: Connection refused
```

Also I'm tried with proxy and without proxy but I give the same error in both.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Does loading the given link in your browser work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer:

I'm in first installation of Composer added a variable named http_proxy to my environment. The value of http_proxy is what you see in that input.

All you need to do is delete that variable from the environment:

[image: image of environment variables]

Answer (score -1):

In windows Go to Enviroment Variable and remove "http_proxy" from List and reset terminal.

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share any new insights that haven't been part of any other existing answer